# How to hide or stop "Mixed Content" popup in IE 11 through javascript or any other language

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, internet-explorer, http

I am using upload services, and I have to use a request over HTTP due to which IE gives me "Mixed Content" popup. My client does not want this. Is there any way to hide or handle it through javascript, JQuery, or C#?

Additional Info: Web Application, C#, Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle Mixed Content warning messages is to deliver all content over HTTPS. Otherwise you open yourself up to all sorts of [nasty](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/06/understanding-risk-of-mixed-content.html) [vulnerabilities](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/03/19/https-mixed-content-still-the-easiest-way-to-break-ssl). If you are hosting your content (images, etc) on your own servers, just change the URL reference in your HTML to the HTTPS version of the URL. If the content is on another host, use their HTTPS URL.

Comment: yes i know. i have already changed every thing to https but there is only single request which is inevitable and i have to deal it on client side to hide it simply. Is is possible ?

Comment: If you're still getting mixed content after changing "every thing" to HTTPS, you may still have resources that aren't being delivered over HTTPS. Go to the target web page, right click to "View source," and find (CTRL + F) "http:" and let us know if anything is returned by that search.